# What is the relationship between saying the 13 Middot and accompanying piyyuṭim?

Tags: selichot, thirteen-attributes

During *seliḥot*, we* interweave saying *piyyuṭim* with the recitation of the 13 *middot*.  This is thematically sensible, since the recitation of the 13 *middot* is supposed to effect God's forgiveness<sup>[1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85922/why-do-we-say-the-13-middos-so-often/85944#85944) [2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/significance-of-13-attributes-of-mercy-in-prayer)</sup>, and the *piyyuṭim* are also on the topic of asking for mercy/forgiveness.

However, more than thematic sensibilities, there seems to be a need for some kind of *piyyuṭ* prior to saying the 13 *middot*, as the Aruch HaShulchan says in [OC 620:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9B) (quoted with English [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85353/4940)).

What is this relationship? Why does the recitation of the 13 *middot* require a *piyyuṭ*? What is the earliest source for such a relationship, and are there contrary opinions?

---

*Based on Artscroll and Koren Ashkenazi *siddurim*/*machzorim*, and Daniel Goldschmidt's *machzorim*/*seliḥot*.

Comment: "piyut" is being used loosely here I guess. There are instances in many rites of but one or two unstructured lines 'prompting' a recitation of the 13 Middot